# Written and verbal incident reports in Time & Temp

Tags: time-and-temp

In Time & Temp by Epidiah Ravachol, every time you file an incident it will be determined if it is written (semi-permanent) or verbal (very temporary).

The text says: "If more than one temp already has an Incident Report, this report will be a written one. Otherwise, it must be a verbal one."

Now, my question is: Are only the incident reports for the first two players verbal and after that, all incident reports are written (no matter what happened to those earlier reports)? Or can the players remove their incident reports from the game by either enduring the penalty or performing the corrective action, so that further reports might again be verbal?

This is rather obscure to me. At the moment, I just count the number of people with *active* incident reports; if it's at least 2, they will receive a written report, otherwise a verbal one.

What is your interpretation of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verbal Incident Reports go away after they provide a penalty once.  Written Incident Reports go away after the temp takes action to remove it.  Count only active Incident Reports across all the temps to determine whether the next one is Verbal or Written.

Comment: Ok, that is exactly what I was confused about. Are the inactive ones counted or not. Where do you take this information from?

Comment: 1. It sort of doesn't make sense without it.  2. I'm pretty sure I asked Eppy about Incident Reports at some point.